# Placing an image in an unordered list box

Tags: html, css

What is the best way to place an image to the right of a list inside the same element box?

What I have is a menu on the left and to the right I want to place an image -

Doing this causes the image to offset the vertical height between menu items:

**CSS**

```
#Menu {
    float: left;
margin-left: 100px;
width: 500px;
text-align: left;
background-color: rgba(246,255,151,.9);
height: 400px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: black;
}
```

**html**

```
<div id="Menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Photos</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a><img src="image.jpg" width="75" height="500"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Upload your code to http://www.jsfiddle.net please and give us the link.

Comment: You can't add `<br>` at that position (outside the `<li>`). If you want to place an image next to the list you need to put it outside the `ul`.

Comment: I took your advice and I got it to work like this. I just wonder if this is the best way to mark it up. http://jsfiddle.net/cQ77G/

Comment: @DavidThomas - This is what I was seeking. I will try to use this and remove the border.  What does setting the position relative and overflow hidden do for an unordered list?

Comment: I've turned that previous comment into an answer, and tried to explain the use of the `overflow: hidden` property:value. As for `position: relative` that was merely the remnant of an alternative approach (that was a little more complex than it needed to be).

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are seeking? if so, you can just the img tag and style it with css. such as if you wanted to the right or left, etc..

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uXNHh/1

```
.nav {
    width:auto;
    margin:auto;
    font: normal 1em Futura, sans-serif;
    color:#333;
}
.nav a {
    color:green;
}
.nav a:hover {
    color:#333;
}
.nav ul li {
    float:left;
    padding:15px;
    list-style:none;
}

    <div class="nav">
        <ul> <a href="#"><li>Home
            <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ec/Happy_smiley_face.png" width="25" height="25"/>
            </li></a>
     <a href="#"><li>About
            <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ec/Happy_smiley_face.png" width="25" height="25"/>
            </li></a>
     <a href="#"><li>Contact
            <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ec/Happy_smiley_face.png" width="25" height="25"/>
            </li></a>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally suggest the following approach, with the HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="image.jpg" width="75" height="500" />
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Photos</a> 
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And CSS:

```
ul {
    /* ensures that the 'ul' doesn't collapse and clip the floated 'li' */
    overflow: hidden;
    /* purely for aesthetics, and to visualise the content-box */
    width: 50%;
    margin: 2em auto;
    border: 2px solid #000;
}
li {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #ffa;
}
li:first-child {
    float: right;
    width: 75px;
    height: 500px;
}

li img {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9JmgE/1/).

This floats the first `li` element to the right, forces the `ul` *not* to 'collapse' around the floated element (which would leave that floated `li` ['sticking out of' the `ul`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9JmgE/1/)).